# Update table "visita" if this have values of other tables

Tags: mysql, netbeans

I put this code in a button, i have table "visita" whit foreign keys of tables "empleado", "departamento", "asunto", "tipo"

```
String n= txtcodigo.getText();
try{
    conexion cc=new conexion();
    Connection cn=cc.Conexion();
    int row = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
    String value =(jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
```

**This part i dont know if is correct** because is very large and i dont know how update foreign keys

```
String query ="UPDATE visita SET 
                    nombre=?, apellido_p=?, apellido_m =?, 
                    compania=?, dia=?, horae=?, recepcionista=? 
                    Empleado_idEmpleado=?, Empleado_Departamento_idDepartamento=?, 
                    asunto_idasunto=?, cliente_idcliente=?, 
                    observaciones=? 
                where idVisita="+value;
```

and i have a table on netbeans, if i want change one value, only click the row

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, when you update columns that are foreign keys, the SQL database server also updates the foreign key indexes. You need not do anything special.

But, if you update a column that's a foreign key so its value no longer matches the table where it points, your UPDATE query will fail by throwing a [foreign key error](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#foreign-key-errors), which shows up in Java as a data integrity exception.  So, it's best to avoid changing those foreign key columns unless you are changing the relationship of your row to the tables it points to. (You probably are not doing that in most cases.)

Example: if you have an existing `visita` record and you only want to update, shall we say, the `receptionista` and `observaciones` colums, use a shorter UPDATE query, and don't mention the columns you wish to leave unchanged.

```
String query ="UPDATE visita 
                  SET recepcionista=?, observaciones=? 
                WHERE idVisita= ?";
```

This is good practice. It makes your intention clearer to the next programmer. And, by not changing the FK columns it saves work on the database server. When you change FK values, the server must verify the foreign key constraints are still met.